# "Formats" Select Menu in WP Editor doesn't show up with correct colour

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, wp-editor

I added the Dropdown "Formats" and defined some custom styles. The followed tutorial is in this [section](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles#Registering_Custom_Styles).

Everything is correct, but there's a small issue:

My custom formats titles within the Dropdown get the same intended CSS style as a preview except for colour. Is it intended by design or am I missing something?

Comment: afaik this is intended, I have noticed it myself and let it be.

Comment: OK, very weird! The other CSS properties are reflected like font-size, text-decoration etc. I will wait, may be someone has a fix or hack for this issue.